# Javascript error when replacing strings

Tags: javascript, string, replace, match

I'm attempting a Javascript challenge from codewars regarding replacing strings.

The instructions are: Your Task :

You have to create a function **GrεεκL33t** which
takes a string as input and returns it in the form of 
(L33T+Grεεκ) Case.
Note: The letters which are not being converted in 
(L33T+Grεεκ) Case should be returned in the lowercase.

```
(L33T+Grεεκ)Case:

A=α (Alpha)      B=β (Beta)      D=δ (Delta)
E=ε (Epsilon)    I=ι (Iota)      K=κ (Kappa)
N=η (Eta)        O=θ (Theta)     P=ρ (Rho)
R=π (Pi)         T=τ (Tau)       U=μ (Mu)      
V=υ (Upsilon)    W=ω (Omega)     X=χ (Chi)
Y=γ (Gamma)
Examples:

GrεεκL33t("CodeWars") = "cθδεωαπs"
GrεεκL33t("Kata") = "κατα"
```

I think the problem is that when I copy the greek characters provided on the web page codewars can't recognise them, it evaluates to:

```
Expected: cθδεωαπs, instead got: cundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefineds
```

My solution is below, anyone have any idea how to get it working?

```
function GrεεκL33t(str){
   var mapObj = {
      A:"α",  B:"β", D:"δ",E:"ε", I:"ι", K:"κ", 
      N:"η", O:"θ", P:"ρ", R:"π", T:'τ', U:'μ', 
      V:'υ', W:'ω', X:'χ', Y:'γ' 
   };

   str = str.replace(/A|B|D|E|I|K|N|O|P|R|T|U|V|W|X|Y/gi, function(matched){
   return mapObj[matched];
   });

   return str;
}
```

Comment: `matched` is not what you think it is.  Read the documentation for `replace()` to learn what parameters it passes.

Comment: Also note that you seem to be missing this requirement: `The letters which are not being converted in (L33T+Grεεκ) Case should be returned in the lowercase.`

Comment: `I copy the greek characters provided on the web page codewars can't recognise them, it evaluates to` If you run your code in the console, you'll see it's not codewars that's the problem. It's your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution can be made to work with just a couple of tweaks (not to suggest there aren't better solutions anyway):

```js
function GrεεκL33t(str){
   var mapObj = {
      a:"α",  b:"β", d:"δ",e:"ε", i:"ι", k:"κ", 
      n:"η", o:"θ", p:"ρ", r:"π", t:'τ', u:'μ', 
      v:'υ', w:'ω', x:'χ', y:'γ' 
   };

   str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/A|B|D|E|I|K|N|O|P|R|T|U|V|W|X|Y/gi, function(matched){ 
   return mapObj[matched];
   });

   return str;
}

alert(GrεεκL33t("Codewars"));
```

You had two problems. First you ignored the requirement for unmatch characters to be returned lower cased. By using `toLowerCase` we fix that problem. The second problem is that your keys for your `mapObj` were all upper case, but in the case of `Codewars` you were passing it lower case characters. Javascript is case sensitive. `mapObj["A"]` is not the same as `mapObj["a"]`. Since we just lowercased the whole string, I just changed the keys in `mapObj` to be lower case too (alternatively you could `matched.toUpperCase()` if you *really, really* want to keep the keys upper case).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand where I had gone wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Why all the complicated replace and match stuff when you have the key already.
Do something like this:

```
function Gr(str) {
    var mapObj = {
        A: "α",
        B: "β",
        D: "δ",
        E: "ε",
        I: "ι",
        K: "κ",
        N: "η",
        O: "θ",
        P: "ρ",
        R: "π",
        T: 'τ',
        U: 'μ',
        V: 'υ',
        W: 'ω',
        X: 'χ',
        Y: 'γ'
    };

    var rebuildString="";

    for (i=0; i<str.length; i++){

        rebuildString += mapObj[str.charAt(i)];
        console.log(rebuildString);

    }

    return rebuildString;

}
Gr("ABD");
```

**edit**

This should work as intended. I did not have time to include lowercase situation, but you will figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/8pwhdpm2/

Comment: Becase OP is feeding it an entire string not a single character.

Comment: @epascarello Yes I was reading the question again and I see it is more complicated. Still doable this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches lowercase letters, even though it is case-insensitive. To fix it, use `str.toUpperCase()`:

```
str = str.replace(/A|B|D|E|I|K|N|O|P|R|T|U|V|W|X|Y/gi, function(matched){
    return mapObj[matched.toUpperCase()];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdvuL4er/